# How to find out how to communicate with a network device

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, buffer

i have a question to a network specialist.
So I have a network device, its a Sky Q receiver.

I found a nodejs plugin which sends Buffers to the device to communicate with it.
To be clear I am able to send remote commands just like using the remote control.
For example he sends a Buffer containing:

`var commandBytes = [4,1,0,0,0,0,Math.floor(224 + button / 16),button % 16]`

where button is a command for example `0` is power.

So my question is, this guy found out how to communicate with this receiver.

Is there a general way how to find out how you can communicate and send commands to a network device?

I tried sniffing everything I can with Wireshark when i start a socket connection to the device I receive a buffer.

Probably my question can't be answered that easy but I wanted to give it a try.

The main point, why im asking stack overflow-community about this is, I have do not a starting point how to ask google this question.

Thank you very much,

Comment: There is no general answer. If you have someone else's program that communicates with the device then you can copy what it does. Or you can be one of the people who programmed the device. Or it might say in the manual.

Comment: @user253751 ok but how did he start. If there is no manual. Do you send like a brute force to the device with thousands of buffer combinations and See what works?

Comment: usually you give up at that point. Nobody except him knows how he started - ask him.

Comment: @FlorianTaut If the communication protocol is not documented (or you don't have access to it), and you can't find an existing implementation to look at, then you just have to reverse engineer the protocol manually, usually by sniffing a working communication between the device and another existing device/tool, seeing what they send during each action performed, and potentially having to decipher the packet data if it uses a binary layout instead of a textual layout.